# AJAX live keyup messed up search

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, ajax

This particular code performs a live AJAX search of the student names. It works on the `keyup` function.

This script is performing AJAX while I press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key and loading the `search.php` file.

**I don't want this function to work on any keys but only alphabet.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  load_data();

  function load_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "search.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
  $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    if (search != '') {
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      load_data();
    }
  });
});
```

This is all I learned so far so if there's any other method to do this it will be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: i used it but it stopped search.php to load data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    load_data();

    function load_data(query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                query: query
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(ev) {
        var searchString = $(this).val();
        if (searchString != '') {
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            if (searchString.match(letters)) {
                load_data(searchString);
            } else {
                load_data();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

-- Edit -- per your comment, the below code will return a sliced value; removing the last or invalid character from our search.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    load_data();

    function load_data(query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                query: query
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(ev) {
        var searchString = $(this).val();
        if (searchString != '') {
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            if (searchString.match(letters)) {
                load_data(searchString);
            } else {
                searchString = searchString.substring(0, searchString.length - 1);
                $('#search_text').val(searchString);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

-- Edit (3rd request) the below code will clear your result div is the last keyup has determined that the search input box is empty (contains no value).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    load_data();

    function load_data(query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                query: query
            },
            success: function(data) {

                $('#result').html(data);

            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(ev) {

        var searchString = $(this).val();

        if (searchString != '') {

            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

            if (searchString.match(letters)) {

                load_data(searchString);

            } else {

                searchString = searchString.substring(0, searchString.length - 1);
                $('#search_text').val(searchString);

            }

        } else {

            $('#result').html('');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: but when i clear search text from search bar it still shows the loaded data. Is there any way we can use 1 backspace for clearing it.

Comment: theres another problem. it still loads search.php when i type a number or press spacebar..i dont want that.

Comment: I removd the load_data() if the condition fails; your original code called your load_data() function when it was null and the condition of letters only wasn't met; I wasn't sure if you left it there on purpose. Now the code will not load_data unless our condition is met.

Comment: you are a life saver thanks a lot it works perfectly. Last think it still loads the data when i clear everything from the searchbar. any solution for that?